# ¿Como buscar index en un array bidimensional en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, busqueda

Tengo un array de 100 elementos que almacena arrays de dos elementos. El primero de tipo Number y el segundo es un String. 
Estos datos los proporciona el usuario 
Necesito encontrar el index del array con el dato String, para poder eliminarlo.

Ya intente hacer un indexOf(String) pero solo me funciona arrays unidimensionales.

```
            var patente = new String
            var número = new Number
            coche = new Array(2)
            autos = new Array (100)
            coche = (patente, número)
            If (autos.length < 100) {
            autos.push(coche);
            }
```

Comment: Muestra un ejemplo breve de la constittución del array para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Para buscar en un array bidimensional puedes intentarlo con [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

Answer (score 2):

Logré solucionarlo con un for que recorra la matriz externa (la de 100 elementos/matrices) y un if que compare la patente con la que estoy buscando

```
for(i=0 ; i<= 100; i++) {
        a = i 
        detector = autos[i]
    }
    if (detector[0] = patente) {
            nuevoArray.splice(a);

        }
```